# Basic: render image field values as an array

Tags: media, entities

I'm looking for a way to list the values of my image field. This list should use the image style "large" for instance. Strangely enough the latter is not visible when I output the field values with `print_r`:

```
[field_fotos] => Array
    (
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [filename] => 7.jpg
                        [uri] => public://default-image-folder/7.jpg
                    )

            )

    )
```

Basicly I'd like to turn all the images that are uploaded to the image field to this list:

```
<div class="bx-thumbs">
    <a href="#" style="background-image:url(thumbs/7.jpg)"></a>
    <a href="#" style="background-image:url(thumbs/6.jpg)"></a>
    <a href="#" style="background-image:url(thumbs/5.jpg)"></a>
    <a href="#" style="background-image:url(thumbs/4.jpg)"></a>
    <a href="#" style="background-image:url(thumbs/3.jpg)"></a>
    <a href="#" style="background-image:url(thumbs/2.jpg)"></a>
    <a href="#" style="background-image:url(thumbs/1.jpg)"></a>
</div>
<div class="bx-container">
    <img src="large/7.jpg" alt="[the alt-text]" />
    <img src="large/6.jpg" alt="[the alt-text]" />
    <img src="large/5.jpg" alt="[the alt-text]" />
    <img src="large/4.jpg" alt="[the alt-text]" />
    <img src="large/3.jpg" alt="[the alt-text]" />
    <img src="large/2.jpg" alt="[the alt-text]" />
    <img src="large/1.jpg" alt="[the alt-text]" />
</div>
```

(Remark the difference between the image folders for thumbs and full images, which is actually their image style [be it simplified for illustration])

Comment: OK, so why don't you use anything like gallery formatter? Or see how they are coded and rip that code?

Comment: Nothing "strange" there :) Field values contain just that - _values_, not the metadata about the field (how it's stored, what widget it uses, the front-end formatter, etc). As @Mołot is hinting at, you either need to use an existing formatter like the one he mentioned (that should get you 99% of the way there to be honest), or code up your own. Which luckily enough is very easy; there's a good example in the field example module in [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples). If you're new to it just edit the question with a bit more detail when you get there, and someone will help

Comment: I tried to figure it out with the Gallery Formatter module but as a frontender, the code doesn't make sense to me (have no idea where to look for what). I thought the "full solution" of this post would finally help me out, but unfortunately it does not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333147/how-to-get-multiple-images-from-a-single-drupal-node-using-php

Comment: @Mołot: Normally I'd use something like GF indeed, but I need a fullscreen background slideshow with thumbnail navigation. There's no module out there that does this, so I have to try my luck with customising coding this plugin in the template: http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenImageBlurEffect/index2.html

Comment: @cptstarling as Clive said, taking ready made gallery formatter would take you 99% there. This 1% is your background part. Most of Drupal modules is open source, so just forking it and loading image elsewhere (background instead of div) should be pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks for the kind directions, I tried to achieve the above with great effort (spent hours), but I'm afraid I don't have the technical background to translate the GF output to background-slides. I feel that I'm pretty close with the Backstretch module though. It doesn't support navigation by default, but I'm trying to get this to work with this reference (without success so far): https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch/issues/308